# reference request for extended kalman filter continuous time system with discrete measurement

Tags: reference-request, kalman-filter

Please refer any good citation (IEEE papers or books) for extended kalman filter continuous time system with discrete   measurements. I mean the prediction part is propogated using continuous model and updation or correction is done at discrete time steps as and when the measurement is available.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

Paul Frogerais, Jean-Jacques Bellanger, and Lotfi Senha, "*Various Ways to Compute the Continuous-Discrete Extended Kalman Filter*",  IEEE TRANSACTIONS ON AUTOMATIC CONTROL, VOL. 57, NO. 4, APRIL 2012